# I'd rather you not talk about Vs. I'd rather you didn't talk about

Tags: grammar

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences:

I'd rather you not talk about what happened last night in front of my mother.

I'd rather you didn't talk about what happened last night in front of my mother.

Imagine that both sentences are said at the current time of speaking, not in the past.

Comment: It seems from the actual question text that you're asking about whether or not to include do-support, but most of your comments imply you're asking about Past or Present Tense. If that's the case, perhaps you should change your first example to *I'd rather you **don't** talk about what happened last night in front of my mother.* Note that ***don't*** or ***didn't*** here both refer to ongoing or future actions - if the reference was to something in the past, it would be *I'd rather you **hadn't talked** about what happened...*

Answer (score 1):

Both sentence mean the exact same thing - the speaker does not want the person being spoken to to talk about what happened last night in front of their mother. There is a subtle difference in the mood of the sentence, as "I'd rather you didn't" uses the subjunctive mood to negatively refer to a hypothetical scenario where the person does tell the speaker's mother. The  phrasing "I'd rather you not" uses the indicative mood to simply express the speaker's desire that their mother not be told. There is essentially no difference in the overall meaning, however - both mean "don't talk about it in front of my mother".

Comment: Thank you, then why in an English course book they have written a sentence like this in the grammar section "This road is dangerous, I'd rather you didn't drive". Why they didn't write " I'd rather you not drive".  Why?

Comment: Moreover, how we can tell when use "present version; I'd rather you not do, and when the past version; I'd rather you didnt do?

Comment: Can we say it's a matter of being polite like when we use "could" "would' when asking someting,  can you open the door vs. could you open the door, based on this -> I'd rather you not drive, vs. I'd rather you didn't drive.

Comment: _I'd rather you didn't_ is much more idiomatic, in my opinion.

Comment: @Shahrooz The subjunctive mood is slightly more indirect, which could possibly be interpreted as politeness or a way of softening the statement in a minor way, but the shades of interpretation are very subtle and probably wouldn't even be considered outside of a direct linguistic comparison like this one. I don't see a strong reason to pick one over the other. If we were referring to a past action, we'd most likely say "I'd rather you *hadn't*".

Comment: So all my explanations and understanding is correct?

Comment: Are you sure *The phrasing "I'd rather you not" uses the indicative mood*? Surely indicative mood is always "tensed, finite", as in *He **shouts*** - but it's *I'd rather he not **shout*** (not *...he not **shouts***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe it's imperative? I'm fairly confident the other one is subjunctive, but I'm not totally sure of "I'd rather you not".

Comment: I think the subject is always ***you*** for an imperative, But just because the OP's example *happens* to include ***you*** is irrelevant. It would still be the same question if the examples had been *I'd rather **he** not talk about what happened last night in front of my mother* or *...rather **he didn't** talk...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, "you" happens to be. It could be any subject, s/he.

Comment: @KateBunting I know, and I've heard it a lot. The question is "Why"? Why is the past tense one is more idiomatic?

Comment: Listening everybody, I'm not saying which one is correct any more; I'm saying, the past tense one is more idiomatic.  [This road is dangerous, so I prefer that you didn't drive vs. I prefer you not to drive.

Comment: @Shahrooz: The syntactic affordances of ***prefer*** aren't the same as ***rather***. Americans prefer *I'd rather you **not** drive* (sometimes *I'd rather you **don't** drive*) where Brits prefer *I'd rather you **didn't** drive*. But *nobody* says *I'd rather you not **to** drive* - it's never idiomatic to include the infinitive marker with ***rather*** in such contexts; we only (optionally) include it with ***prefer***.

Answer (score 1):

As a Brit, I *really* don't like OP's first version (*without* "do-support"). Here's the [BrE usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would%20rather%20you%20not%2Cwould%20rather%20you%20didn%27t&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

...where I expect most of even that small amount of the "non-standard" instances are misclassified AmE texts anyway. It's also worth pointing out that the usage was virtually unknown even in AmE a century ago, and [it's still a *minority* usage today...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would%20rather%20you%20not%2Cwould%20rather%20you%20didn%27t&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

...so I'd advise using do-support. I don't believe it's worth postulating a possible difference in *meaning* anyway - even if a few Americans think there's a difference, that would probably be more than offset by confusion among others who find the usage unnatural (not *just* Brits, I'm sure).

---

Note that when the *speaker* is the subject, we don't normally repeat the pronoun anyway, and do-support is rarely included. On both sides of the Atlantic it's...

> *I'd rather not talk about it*
> ...not...
> *I'd rather I didn't talk about it*
> ...or....
> *I'd rather I not talk about it*

Comment: and who said the sentence was "I'd rather I didn't talk or I'd rather I not talk about it?

Comment: Don't be silly. We don't have a different rule for first person singular as opposed to any other pronoun (or indeed, any other *subject noun*) in such contexts. The important factors here are negation and do-support, not which specific subject noun is in play.